# Remove a javascript value "cached"

Tags: javascript

I have a job in my javascript that I have to present the "real" content of a file with

```
file.open('get', 'teste2.txt', true);
```

Unfortunately, I'm always presenting old versions of the file. The old file info is in the cache... and every time I use CTRL+R it changes...

How can I guaranty that I'm showing the last version of the file? Any way to clear this cache value?

Something like:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

But... that works :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a salt in the query...

```
file.open('get', 'teste2.txt?_='+(new Date().getTime()), true);
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried so many things... :D like: function clearBrowserCache() {
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
} ----- This is the only thing that worked for me, really thanks